# Как получить конкретное значение атрибута XML?

Tags: xml, golang

XML:

```
<users>
  <user type="admin">
    <name>Elliot</name>
    <social>
      <facebook>https://facebook.com</facebook>
      <twitter>https://twitter.com</twitter>
      <youtube>https://youtube.com</youtube>
    </social>
  </user>  
</users>
```

Мне нужно получение значение несколько полей. Это `name`, `facebook`, `twitter`, `youtube`.

Как я могу это сделать, для того, чтобы можно было использовать структуры для определения полей (или что-то другое без цикла `for range`)? допустим:

```
var TwitterName = Field.Twitter
var Facebook = Field.Facebook
var Youtube = Field.Youtube
```

Было бы отлично узнать реализацию этого всего :).

Comment: https://gist.github.com/kwmt/6135123#file-parsetvdb-go раз

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27527561/golang-how-to-extract-part-of-an-xml-file-as-a-string два

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40095427/golang-parsing-xml-to-struct Тръи

Comment: @hedgehogues я рылся на первых двух страницах гугла, дальше я не зашел) не знаю откуда вы это достали, но 3 вариант мне подошел)

Comment: Скажите, что конкретно Вы гуглили. Ну, ей богу, мне интересно

Comment: На будущее https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

Comment: @hedgehogues golang xml parsing, golang xml get value, golang xml get fields, golang парсинг xml файлов, работа с xml,  всякую чушь выдавало мне

Comment: Не очень понимаю, как Вы смотрели. Все те же самые ссылки. Прямо очень странные вещи Вы говорите

Comment: @hedgehogues не знаю, естно, может индексирует по разному, но ладно.. Кстати можете помочь с вопросом? - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/861565/xml-выдает-none-значение-поля

Answer (score 2):

```
type Social struct {
    Facebook string `xml:"facebook"`
    Twitter  string `xml:"twitter"`
    Youtube  string `xml:"youtube"`
}

type User struct {
    Name string `xml:"name"`
    Social Social `xml:"social"`
}

type Users struct {
    Users []User `xml:"user"`
}

func main() {
    xmlFile, err := os.Open("xml.xml")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer xmlFile.Close()

    data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)

    var u Users
    xml.Unmarshal(data, &u)

    fmt.Println(u.Users[0].Social)
}
```

Вывод

> {https://facebook.com https://twitter.com https://youtube.com}