# XML, выдает "none" значение поля

Tags: xml, golang

У меня есть XML код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Packer3>
    <Atlas>
        <FirstStepName>Andrew</FirstStepName>
    </Atlas>
</Packer3>
```

Я паршу поля `FirstStepName`, записываю в файл **data.txt**, в файле **data.txt** у меня напротив имени полей пишет `"none"`, почему я не знаю, вроде бы всё правильно делаю.

Код:

```
type Blob struct {
    Name string `xml:"Packer3>Atlas>FirstStepName"`
}

func main() {
    var v = Blob{"none"}
    var err error
    var data []byte

    data, err = ioutil.ReadFile("packer3.xml")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    err = xml.Unmarshal(data, &v)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    f, err := os.OpenFile("data.txt", os.O_CREATE | os.O_APPEND | os.O_WRONLY, 0644)

    if _, err = f.WriteString("FirstStepName: "+v.Name); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш тип `Blob` *уже* примет в себя корневой элемент. Так что:

```golang
type Blob struct {
    Name string `xml:"Atlas>FirstStepName"`
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/FJPKWGglFVi.

Comment: Спасибо большое!